# What can go wrong in the following scenario?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have a `struct` defintion as following:

```
typedef struct {
  UINT   idLength;
  UINT * ids;
} AsnObjectIdentifier;
```

I have a function which has a stack allocated variable of the above struct and I pass this variable as reference to some other function to populate values in it.

```
void someFunc() {
  //code
  AsnObjectIdentifier temp;    //this is a stack allocated variable
  someOtherFunc(temp);
}
```

In the function that populates the the above stack variable I am creating a heap allocated `UINT` array and assigning it to `ids`.

```
void someOtherFunc(AsnObjectIdentifier& oidVar) {
  //code
  UINT* arr = new UINT[someSize];     //this is a heap allocated variable
  oidVar.ids = arr;
  //some other code
}
```

When I return to the calling function I have a stack variable which internally contains a heap allocated variable.

Am I doing something wrong? Am I playing with two worlds of different memories? Can it lead to problems?

Also if in the `someFunc()` I create a new `AsnObjectIdentifier` variable and allocate memory to it using `malloc` can I assign the `UINT` array from the stack allocated variable to this new heap allocated `AsnObjectIdentifier` variable? Will there be any problems with this as well?

Comment: What you're doing is okay, as long as you remember to `delete[]` the memory you have allocated. Or better yet, use a `std::vector` instead of manual memory allocation.

Comment: Oh, in C++ you should almost *never* use `malloc` directly. First of all try to avoid pointers if at all possible. If not then try to use smart pointers and their ownership semantics. Or for collections/"arrays" of objects use `std::vector` or `std::array`. Or, as a last resort, use `new` or `new[]`.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing something wrong?

Yes, I would say **Ownership** is an issue. From what you have shown the ownership is unclear and it is not clear who should delete `arr` (and how will they know that they should use `delete[]`).

For this reason, the conventional meaning of a raw pointer (in `c++`, not in `c`) is usually "non-owning".

In your example, the straightforward way is probably just use a `std::vector<UINT>` instead of `AsnObjectIdentifier struct`.

> Am I playing with two worlds of different
>   memories? Can it lead to problems?

It doesn't look like that, but you should steer away from *hand rolling memory management*. A `new[]` or in the extreme even just any kind of `new` or memory allocation is an indication that you are hand rolling.

Comment: I cannot change the `struct` to `std::vector<UINT>` because it comes from `snmp.h` from Microsoft. This is the reason i was worried about all this

Comment: How can I prevent hand rolling? I learnt C++ years back when I was taught to do manual memory management. Could you link me to some resources for automatic memory management

Comment: @NavjotSingh i cannot right now, but it usually boils down to: use the std:: containers like vector,  set, map, unique_ptr , shared_ptr, etc.